# Not able to calculate the correct product of Pythagorean triplet from the sum of the triplets

Tags: c#

A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural number, a < b < c, for which a^2 + b^b = c^2.
We are given the sum of Pythagorean triplet which is "number" in my case and we have to find the maximum product of a, b and c. 
I am giving input 5040 as it is the sum of 1260,1680 and 2100. These three numbers forms a Pythagorean triplet. My program should give 4445280000 output as it is the product of the numbers, but it is giving 150312704. Here is my code. I have watched the variables values of a b and c which are correct but the program is not printing the right product of it.

```
int noofcases = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 0; i < noofcases; i++)
{
    int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    long result = -1;
    int a, b, c;
    for( a = 1; a <= number/3; a++)
    {
        b = (((number * number) - (2 * a * number)) / ((2 * number) - (2 * a)));
        c = number - a - b;
        if((a*a) + (b*b) == (c*c))
        {
            result = (a * b * c);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: The maximum value that can be stored in an `int` is 2,147,483,647.  Your number 4,445,280,000 is larger than that.  Consider using a `long` or `Int64` instead

Comment: seems like a project Euler task if i remember correctly. please post the task description to improve the quality of your post.

Comment: yes it is a project euler question.

Comment: i have used the long data type for result.

Comment: You are using `int`s for your multiplication, which will produce an `int` result without explicit casting.  Just use `long` values instead if you are expecting to deal with results larger than `int.MaxValue`;

Comment: i thought explicit casting was not required as it is int can be converted to long implicitly. But still this program isn't able to pass three test cases. I don't understand what wen wrong here. @MartinParkin

Comment: First the multiplication is done using ints (which truncates the result), then the result is converted to long. `result = (long)a * b * c;` would work. Btw. 4,445,280,000  is not the maximum product. It's the last but not the maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `int` in C# is a 32-bit signed integer, which has a range between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647.

This means that the maximum value that can be stored in an `int` is 2,147,483,647.  Your expected value, 4,445,280,000, is more than twice that maximum value.

When your `int` value exceeds the maximum of 2,147,483,647, it will *roll over* to -2,147,483,648 and then count back to 0.

Therefore, 4,445,280,000 will become 150,312,704 as you are experiencing.

Using a `long` for your result *only* will not work, because the output of any `int` multiplied by an `int` will always be an `int` unless you use explicit casting.

Simply switch your `int`s to `long`s in your program and it will operate as you expect:

```
int noofcases = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 0; i < noofcases; i++)
{
    long number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    long result = -1;
    long a, b, c;
    for (a = 1; a <= number / 3; a++)
    {
        b = (((number * number) - (2 * a * number)) / ((2 * number) - (2 * a)));
        c = number - a - b;
        if ((a * a) + (b * b) == (c * c))
        {
            result = (a * b * c);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Output:

```
1
5040
4445280000
```

Comment: But still three test cases are not cleared from this code. I don't know what is missing in the code. Unfortunately the values of test cases are not revealed by project euler.

Comment: You are taking the last result, not the maximum result. `long r = a * b * c; if (r > result) { result = r; }`

Comment: ok ok I understand. Thank you sir. i have passed all the test cases.